# When running a unit test on the controller save method, for some reason a grails models save method returns simply null

Tags: unit-testing, grails

So we have a unit test which is failing where we attempt to call the save method on a model. This for some reason returns true when we run the method in reality. We've mocked the domain in the setUp method.

Does anyone know why the heck the save method is returning null?

Source Code here: http://gist.github.com/485365

We're running Grails 1.3.1

Comment: did you try the fix anyway, even though it is different versions?  I might also affect 1.3.1.

Answer (score -1):

this might be an issue if you are using 1.3.3.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6482

Comment: did you originally specify 1.3.1?

Comment: Nope, I just added it to the question. I didn't downvote. Not sure who did.

Comment: @Zachary Spencer -- ok -- im still stuck on 1.2.0 :(, but i knew of mockDomain issues in 1.3.3 so just posted the link.  Wierd, google is not being helpful.  would try the mailing list or irc...